# Align contents of TableLayout to center

Tags: android, xml, tablelayout

I have a TextView which centers correctly, but when I want to center the contents of the table if doesn't align to center. I tried

```
layout_gravity="center"
```

and

```
gravity="center"
```

Both are not working. What can I do?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TextView
         android:id="@+id/date"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:gravity="center"
         android:padding="20dp"  />
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/table"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_below="@id/date" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Did you try it on the `TableLayout` itself or elements within the table?

Comment: TableLayout itself. I create the TableRows programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about exact output you are expecting from the layout, but you can try to set width of the table to "wrap_content" and use attributes android:layout_centerInParent="true"  or android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" or android:layout_centerVertical="true" on TableLayout.

I hope this helps.